# How to prevent JavaScript form.submit() from ignoring required fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a HTML form that contains some text field and file input for an image. It has required fields for the texts, it also does some client side validation of the image selected with JavaScript (jQuery).

Here is the form:

```
<form name="addbookform" id="addbookform" action="processaddbook.php" method="POST">
<p />
<input name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required />
<p />
<textarea name="description" id="description" cols=30 rows=4 placeholder="Enter a short description">
</textarea>
<p />
<input name="image" id="image" type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" />
<p />
<input type="button" id="finishbutton" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

To do client side check with the image I wrote some JavaScript code (with jQuery), and linked it onto the `finishbutton`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#finishbutton').click( function() {
        var fileInput = document.getElementById("bookimage");
        if (fileInput.value == "") {
            // We can just submit the form without an image.
            addbookform.submit();
        } else {
            // Check for image size and other properties...
            if (success == true) {
                addbookform.submit();
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Now the image check works as expected (reporting error or valid with the images), however, there are a required field in the `name` input on the form. When the image check is passed (or no image), the submit function is called, but it seems like HTML has skipped the required field validation.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: I would use a normal `type=submit` button and then use `$("#addbookform").on("submit", ...)` to do any additional validation, preventing submit if the image validation fails, but otherwise just allowing the default submit behaviour to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think instead of forcing the form to submit, do the other way around: **Prevent the form to submit if something goes wrong**

1. Change the submit button type to submit. This will render a button with form submit action when click.
2. Change the event to work on form submit instead of button click.
3. Set a flag value to true. If by the end of validation, flag is false, prevent submit.
4. Check your image. If anything goes wrong, change flag.
5. Check your input. If anything goes wrong, change flag.
6. **(Note)** Until now, there is no stopping the form from submitting. Only change the flag.
7. At the end of validation. Check your flag. If false, prevent submit. If true, do nothing.

In form submission, if you `return false;` at any point of the submitting event, the submission will be canceled.

Comment: If you want to avoid a double checking on the fields already marked with "required" attribute, you could ask to the form additemform.checkValidity() which returns true only when all the required inputs have some value. But definetly, catching the form submit event would be more controllable than capturing button click to prevent an invalid submission.